# Was the quadratic function derived?

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, quadratics

By quadratic function, I mean :

$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$

Because the specific constant have a different role, e.g. increasing $a$ has a role of narrowing or inverting the parabola, I'm thinking if this was a derived function/equation. If so, how was this derived?

Additionally, for an even more general equation of a circle for instance:

$$x^2+y^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$

What would be the role of each of the constants: $D$, $E$ and $F$?

And how can I go further into this?

Comment: The general equation for a circle is $(x – h)^2 + (y – k)^2 = r^2$, where $r$ is the radius.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "derived"

Comment: You can also write any quadratic as its roots with a vertical stretch factor, and as a difference of two squares with vertical displacement and stretch factors. Looking at either/both of those tells you much more directly about the quadratic than the general equation you're using. As it is, the coefficient of $x$ doesn't say much directly at all, and the constant has the same effect as in any equation.

Comment: @pseudoeuclidean, By derived I mean if there is a derivation to how such equations were established in the first place.

Comment: If you're looking for geometrically-interpretable parameters, then you're using the wrong general equation of a circle; use the one parametrized by center and radius, as @Leonhard has told you.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician, No, I'm just finding what the constants denote. e.g. y  = mx + c, c is a constant(that's what everyone says) but c is the y intercept.

Comment: Right, and my point was that those constants don't have as much of a geometric meaning as when you complete the square and convert the general circle equation into center-radius format. In the same way, if you started out with $ax+by+c=0$, there's nothing (easily) geometrically interpretable there unless you make a few algebraic manipulations.

Comment: That seems true

Comment: But, without paremetrizing(which I'm unfamiliar with), there doesn't seem to be such a manipulation for the equation of the circle, is there?

Comment: I already mentioned "completing the square"; the answer by @Shraddheya below has more or less done it implicitly, which is why the radius and the center's coordinates were obtained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the additional part of your question, for the following equation of circle, $$x^2+y^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$
the co-ordinates of the center of the circle are $(-\frac{D}{2}, -\frac{E}{2})$ (the role of the constants $D$ and $E$ right there) and the radius of the circle is $\sqrt{\frac{D^2}{4} + \frac{E^2}{4}-F}$; so for fixed $D$ and $E$, $F$ is inversely proportional to the radius(size) of the circle.

EDIT:
Here is an "independent" geometric meaning of the constant $F$: square of the length of the tangent to the circle from the origin.
$1$. If the origin lies outside the circle then $2$ tangents of equal length can be drawn to the circle. Here $F$ is positive and it's square root gives the lengths of these tangents.
$2$. If the origin is inside the circle, then $F$ is negative. Its square root(and hence the length) is imaginary. Hence no tangent can be drawn to the circle from origin in this case.
$3$. If the origin is on the circle($F=0$) then, length of the tangent from it is $0$. Note that length in all these cases denote the distance from the origin to the point of tangency. Here these points coincide. Hence the length is $0$.

Comment: I meant a more informal meaning to them, e.g. in y = mx + c, c is a constant but it denotes the y-intercept INDEPENDETLY.

Comment: Well, I think that $y$-intercept is infact a more "formal" meaning attached to $c$ than something like $F$ related to size of a circle. Also, I am not sure what you meant to imply by *highlighting* the word "independently".

Comment: you see that you had a point that if we group them, for example, what you had done above for finding a radius, they do make sense, but what would they be INDEPENDENTLY?

Comment: I have added an "independent" geometric meaning for the constant $F$ and I believe you were convinced with the geometric meaning of the constants $D$ and $E$ as being sufficiently "independent".

Answer (score 2):

I think you're seeing this the wrong way around. It wasn't that we chose the standard form $ax^2+bx+c$ because we could change the geometry. The choice was simply the most natural way of writing a quadratic. Once we had the most simple form, we then looked at the geometric implications of altering the constants.